# Boost serialization : ensure data safety over socket transmition

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm using boost 1.53 and serialization to transfer an array of 520 floats over TCP/IP. I put a debug code printout to see the amount of data to be send : it's about 5 K. No problem for me here, but this value somehow depends on the actual data to be serialized. It could be 5400, 5500 and so on.

The question is : what is the right way to receive such data block? For the moment I use `read_some()` call. But as I've figured out it doesn't guarantee that the whole serialized block of data will be read out. Am I wrong?

How to ensure that there will be a complete archive at RX side? Is there any exception to be thrown when it is not possible to deserialize a chunk of data?

Answer (score 2):

as far as tcpip packet can be received to a number of smaller packets so I'd recommend to add some additional data to tcpip
something like this:

1. serialize you data to stream
2. get size of stream
3. send to tcpip buffer starting with size of stream and then data from the stream

receiver reads size and then reads the rest of the packet.

after you received the full packet - call deserialization

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Alexander. Do you know if there is any exception to be thrown from the deserializer in case of any issues with it?

Comment: as far as i remeber - yes. but I would not rely on that. There may be situations when data is wrong but it is recognized as the right.
so add size and receive the whole packet and then deserialize

Comment: @Dmitry here's a list of exceptions raisable from Boost Serialization: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html. Yes, `serialize()` functions are `void`, so indeed exceptions are the primary error reporting mechanism.

Comment: Just one idea for the suggested solution - I think I have to serialize the size of the data stream too, as I should overcome potential LE/BE issues, am I right?

Comment: If you serialize size as text - there will be no problem with endianess. If in binary - write and read in portable way. E.g: char byte0 = (char)(size >> 24); etc

Comment: @Dmitry There is a Portable Archive implementation by EOS on codeplex: http://epa.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `read_some` is potentially a no-op on conforming implementations<sup>[1]</sup>.

Instead do a loop using `read()` and `gcount()`, like:

```
std::istream& is = gotten_from_somewhere_or_a_parameter();

std::vector<byte> v(256);
std::streamsize bytes_read;
do
{
    is.read(v.data(),v.size());
    bytes_read = stream.gcount ();

    // do something with the bytes read
} while(bytes_read);
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Notably, gcc's standard library implementation seems to always return something for `std::filebuf` but on MSVC, the first call will simply always return `0` bytes read :)